# Windows Server Failover Cluster (File Server)

Tags: windows, failover

I am planning to create a windows server failover cluster for file server. However, I do not have any shared storage available which I can connect to the cluster.

Is there anyway to use the local disk instead as a storage?

Comment: You want to failover a local disk? That's not possible. Maybe DFS is for you.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Another question is does DFS server has to be up and running all the times? I have setup 2 servers, eg Server1 and Server2 for DSF and replication. I have configured Namespace in Server1 but when Server1 is down, I unable to access file share using the namespace.

Comment: The namespace server has to be online, yes. You could use your DCs for that.